# What is the difference between the following two methods in Java

Tags: java

What is the difference between the following two methods and which one is the best?

Method 1 :

```
private String getStringValue(){
  if(condition)
     return string1;
  return string2;
}
```

Method 2 :

```
private String getStringValue(){
 if(condition)
     return string1;
 else
     return string2;
}
```

Comment: there is none. It's only a matter of readability

Comment: I prefer `return condition ? string1 : string2;`.

Comment: I would recommend using brackets though, far clearer.

Comment: There is no difference. Both generate the same bytecode.

Comment: the first one is being a jerk to whoever has to maintain his code after he is gone, the second thinks about the people reading the code after him.

Comment: @DonBottstein ternary for the win!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between these methods: the `else` in the first method can be safely deleted, because once the `if` branch is taken, the execution leaves the method unconditionally.

There are companies that prefer one of the two variants in order to achieve consistency among the code written by large groups of developers.

Answer (score 4):

The second is more readable, that's all, there is no logical difference.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the 2 methods, but readability wise both has problems.
Make sure you wrap if blocks with `{` `}`

```
if(condition){
  return string1;
}return string2;

if(condition){
     return string1;
}else{
     return string2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is how they are written.

This method contains full logic for readability:

```
private String getStringValue(){
   if(condition)
      return string1;
   else
      return string2;
}
```

This method acts the exact same way, but is written in a short-cut manner:

```
private String getStringValue(){
   if(condition)
      return string1;
   return string2;
}
```